# Topic outline: "Show 14 more examples, 1 more sections"

Tags: bug, documentation, plurals

Whenever you view a topic that has too many examples and exactly one special section ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams)), the bottom of the topic outline says:

> Show 14 more examples, 1 more sections

"Sections" shouldn't be plural here.

Now to start working on armor that can block a giant S…